# How to implement __eq__ for set inclusion test?

Tags: python, set, equality

I am running into an issue where I'm adding an instance to a set and then later testing to see whether or not that object exists in that set. I've overridden `__eq__()` but it doesn't get called during the inclusion test. Do I have to override `__hash__()` instead? If so, how would I implement `__hash__()` given that I need to hash the tuple, the list, and the dictionary?

```
class DummyObj(object):

    def __init__(self, myTuple, myList, myDictionary=None):
        self.myTuple = myTuple
        self.myList = myList
        self.myDictionary = myDictionary

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.myTuple == other.myTuple and \
            self.myList == other.myList and \
            self.myDictionary == other.myDictionary

    def __ne__(self, other):
        return not self.__eq__(other)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    list1 = [1, 2, 3]
    t1    = (4, 5, 6)
    d1    = { 7 : True, 8 : True, 9 : True }
    p1 = DummyObj(t1, list1, d1)

    mySet = set()

    mySet.add(p1)

    if p1 in mySet:
        print "p1 in set"
    else:
        print "p1 not in set"
```

Comment: Maybe you could write the unit test for us that you expect to be successful? I get `p1 in set` with your code. Should I get something else?

Comment: hashing mutable objects isn't generally a good idea...

Comment: See http://wiki.python.org/moin/DictionaryKeys for why @mgilson is right.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From the [documentation on sets](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html):

> The set classes are implemented using dictionaries. Accordingly, the
>   requirements for set elements are the same as those for dictionary
>   keys; namely, that the element defines both __eq__() and __hash__().

The [__hash__ function documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__) suggests xor-ing the hashes of components together. As others have mentioned, it's generally not a good idea to hash mutable objects, but if you really need to, this works:

```
class DummyObj(object):

    ...

    def __hash__(self):
        return (hash(self.myTuple) ^
                hash(tuple(self.myList)) ^
                hash(tuple(self.myDictionary.items())))
```

And checking to see if it works:

```
p1 = DummyObj(t1, list1, d1)
p2 = DummyObj(t1, list1, d1)
mySet = set()
mySet.add(p1)

print "p1 in set", p1 in mySet
print "p2 in set", p2 in mySet
```

This prints:

```
$ python settest.py 
p1 in set True
p2 in set True
```

Answer (score -3):

Well, my guess would be `__eq__` or `__ne__` may not called by python when comparing objects using the 'in' operator. I'm not positive what the specific "rich comparison" operator would be, looking at the documentation, but overriding `__cmp__` should solve your problem as python uses it by default to perform object comparisons if a more suitable "rich comparison" operator is not implemented.

Comment: You're wrong. `__eq__` and `__ne__` work just fine, the problem is the lack of (custom, correct) hash function.

Comment: Why would you answer if you're just guessing?