# BFS implementation in python not fast enough

Tags: python, algorithm, breadth-first-search

I'm trying to speed up my BFS algorithm, that solves rush hour games. I feed the algorithm a parent board, and I'm wondering whether the implementation of my BFS algorithm or the building blocks used in my code that I call from the algorithm should change.

This is the BFS algorithm at the moment:

```
def start_bfs(start_grid):
vehicle_dict = dict()
queue = deque()
queue.append(pd.DataFrame(start_grid))
while queue:
    vehicle_dict.clear()
    df_grid = queue.pop()
    vehicle_dict = set_up(vehicle_dict,df_grid)
    for key, value in vehicle_dict.iteritems():
        check_adjecent(key, value, vehicle_dict)
        movelist, object_location, direction = get_movelist(key, value, vehicle_dict, df_grid)
        if not movelist:
            continue
        while movelist:
                node = movelist.pop(0)
                new_vehicle_dict = move(node, copy.deepcopy(vehicle_dict), df_grid)
                child_df_grid = create_board(new_vehicle_dict)
                if not True in [child_df_grid.equals(x) for x in archive]:
                    check_goal(node[1], new_vehicle_dict, archive, df_grid, child_df_grid) 
                    queue.append(copy.deepcopy(child_df_grid))
                    archive.append(copy.deepcopy(child_df_grid))
        archive.append(copy.deepcopy(df_grid))
```

The start grid, for example, looks like this:

```
 start_grid = [['.', '.', 'T', 'F', 'F', 'E'],
         ['.', '.', 'T', '.', '.', 'E'],
         ['.', '.', 'T', 'R', 'R', 'E'],
         ['.', '.', '.', 'C', '.', '.'],
         ['A', 'B', 'B', 'C', '.', '.'],
         ['A', '.', '.', 'C', 'H', 'H']]
```

Is there something I'm doing inherently wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do your `set_up(vehicle_dict,df_grid)`, `get_movelist(key, value, vehicle_dict, df_grid)`, and/or `move(node, copy.deepcopy(vehicle_dict), df_grid)` modify the `df_grid` passed into them? If not, I highly doubt many of those deep copies you're doing are necessary. You'll want to carefully check to make sure yourself, but I think the following lines dont need all those deep copies:

- `queue.append(copy.deepcopy(child_df_grid))`
- `archive.append(copy.deepcopy(child_df_grid))`
- `archive.append(copy.deepcopy(df_grid))`

I think you can also move `archive.append(copy.deepcopy(df_grid))` to *before* the while loop, so that you can immediately discard moves that do nothing.

Checking whether you've seen a board before using

```
if not True in [child_df_grid.equals(x) for x in archive]:
```

also seems inefficient. What kind of object is `archive` anyway? I'd recommend using a [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set) (*not* a list!). That may not work correctly if your boards are represented as `pd.DataFrame`s though (which also seems kind of overcomplicated at first glance here without seeing how your other functions are implemented). A simple custom class to contain your data, with [correctly implemented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15326985/how-to-implement-eq-for-set-inclusion-test) `__eq__` and `__hash__` functions (required for set) would probably be better. Then you can efficiently check if something is truly new using:

```
if not child_df_grid in archive:
```

Comment: Archive is just a list, I'm going to try the set alternative.

Comment: It's true that saving the boards as data frames is excessive. I wasn't aware of the extra computing time that a pd.dataframe could give

Comment: Although, hashing a dict isn't possible either. I'm not sure if this will increase my computing time, for I'm working with dict and pd.dataframes

Comment: Yeah hashing is problematic there, which is why I suggested building your own custom class to hold your data. I dont think it needs to be fancy, just a class wrapped around a simple matrix/nested lists, with a few supporting functions (like `__eq__` and `__hash__` and anything else you may find useful)